# La terminal no devuelve el control con conexión ssh en github

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, ssh

mi problema es que cuando quiero testear mi conexión con ssh en linux con github (`ssh -T git@github.com`) no me devuelve el control o el prompt. Es como si estuviera congelado. Alguien sabe a qué se debe? Lo curioso es que solo pasa con distribuciones que NO son basadas en Ubuntu. No funciona en Fedora ni Manjaro pero sí en cualquier distro de Ubuntu.
Explico mejor, luego de ejecutar el primer comando me pide mi frase de contraseña, la ingreso y la terminal se queda ahí, en blanco. Y tengo que hacer C-c  para volver al prompt pero sin que pueda verificar mi conexión.

La salida del comando: ssh -vT git@github.com

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/andres/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/andres/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/andres/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/andres/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andres/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-4cec2db4
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-4cec2db4
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/andres/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/andres/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/andres/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:+0OFBPQpoarSpWnIK9gKAv4m1ywC4ueFT+WeWU1OeCo agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:+0OFBPQpoarSpWnIK9gKAv4m1ywC4ueFT+WeWU1OeCo agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/andres/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:+0OFBPQpoarSpWnIK9gKAv4m1ywC4ueFT+WeWU1OeCo agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.114.3]:22).
debug1: pkcs11_del_provider: called, provider_id = (null)
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env XMODIFIERS = "@im=ibus"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Saludos desde Manjaro con KDE, acá estoy leyendo a github decirme `Hi alfabravoteam! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`. Más bien cuéntanos qué terminal usas (bash, ksh, alguna otra cosa) y qué programa usas (depende del windowmanager). Autenticas con publickey o con credenciales?

Comment: Saludos, exactamente ese mensaje es el que espero. Y como mencioné me sale cuando estoy en Ubuntu y derivas pero en otras distros no me sale ese mensaje. Auntentico con publickey y uso bash con la terminal de gnome. Explico mejor, luego de ejecutar el primer comando me pide mi frase de contraseña, la ingreso y la terminal se queda ahí, en blanco. Y tengo que hacer C-c  para volver al prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene pinta de ser un problema de configuración, no de SSH ni de github. Algunos [reportes](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=487423) hablan de líos con iptables que logran resolver con

`sudo /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -j TOS --set-tos 0x00`

Para poner el ToS en normal-service.

Otros indican que lograron que funcione después de revisar que `/dev/pts` exista y tenga permisos para usarse.

Otros [hablan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5935584/236345) de líos en el `~/.bashrc` que puede tener líneas en conflicto con estos procesos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! El primer comando lo solucionó. Debió ser un problema con las iptables como mecionas.

Comment: @andres19riv me alegra poder ayudar! Recuerda guardar la configuración de tu iptables para no tener que hacer lo mismo cada vez que inicies.